# Shows a list with the names of all the movies and the number of actors associated >> ORACLE <<

Tags: oracle

Well, I need to call on the screen what was asked, but how?
I have three tables, containing the names of the films, which contains the name of the actors and the relational containing the 'ids' to display correctly. But I came across this and are difficult to solve, here are the tables ...

```
To create Actors table

create table tb_ator(
        id_ator NUMBER (4) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
             nome_ator VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
    );


To Create Films table

create table tb_filme(
      id_filme NUMBER (4) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
      nome_filme VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL 
);

And finaly, the relational 

create table ator_filme(
      id_filme NUMBER (4) references tb_filme(id_filme),
      id_ator NUMBER (4) references tb_ator(id_ator)
);
```

How do I solve this with the inner join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT F.nome_filme, COUNT(AF.id_ator) AS actors 
FROM ator_filme AF INNER JOIN tb_ator A ON AF.id_ator = A.id_ator 
     INNER JOIN tb_filme F ON AF.id_filme = F.id_filme
GROUP BY F.nome_filme;
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, but how could display that does not contain? With a "left join"? And what are these 'F' and 'A'?

Comment: AF, A and F are just aliases to the tables, so that you don't need to type them again

Comment: What do you want to do with the left join? I didn't understand the question

Comment: Junior, please don't forget to up vote this answer and mark as responded if you think it resolved your question. Thks.