# ORACLE, display record according to its related

Tags: database, oracle

I have three tables, one containing the names of some movies and their 'id', also have a table with the names of the actors and their 'id', and finally the third table that is relational, which has the id of the movie and the id of the actor. What I need? Let's assume that the Actor table there is the record of 'NEMO' 'Dori' and 'Jack' and the table film for the record 'Finding Nemo' and 'TITANIC', and I need ONLY view the name of the movie that contains the actors 'NEMO' and 'DORI' (which were registered with the id of the movie 'Finding Nemo'); Here are the tables below:

Movie table

```
create table tb_filme(
      id_filme NUMBER (4) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
      nome_filme VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL 
);
```

Actor table

```
create table tb_ator(
    id_ator NUMBER (4) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
         nome_ator VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
);
```

Actor and Movie table

```
create table ator_filme(
      id_filme NUMBER (4) references tb_filme(id_filme),
      id_ator NUMBER (4) references tb_ator(id_ator)
);
```

Remembering that my result to be 'Finding Nemo' only

Comment: What if I add another movie, say 'NEMO alone' where I only hav NEMO and not DORI? Would you show it?

Comment: If there are two movies contains the NEMO and DORI actors will appear the two, but if there is only the NEMO and there is a DORI, do not display

Comment: I would recommend you understanding of join operation. You've posted another question yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40225726/shows-a-list-with-the-names-of-all-the-movies-and-the-number-of-actors-associate/40225874#40225874  that relates to similar problem of joining tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need something like this:

```
select nome_filme
from tb_filme
       inner join ator_filme
         using(id_filme)
       inner join tb_ator
         using(id_ator)
where nome_ator in ('NEMO', 'Dori')
group by nome_filme    
having count(id_ator) = 2
```

This simply joins your tables to find all the movies with NEMO and/or Dori, then it aggregates to get only one row for movie and checks that all the 2 actors are in the movie.

This can be re-written in many different ways, I believe this uses basic concepts and can be quite self-explanatory.

With this data

```
insert into tb_ator values (1, 'NEMO');
insert into tb_ator values (2, 'Jack');
insert into tb_ator values (3, 'Dori');
insert into tb_filme values (1, 'Finding NEMO');
insert into tb_filme values (2, 'TITANIC');
insert into tb_filme values (3, 'NEMO ALONE');
insert into ator_filme values (1,1);
insert into ator_filme values (1,3);
insert into ator_filme values (2,2);
insert into ator_filme values (3,1);
```

this gives:

```
NOME_FILME
---------------------
Finding NEMO
```